# The Crisis of Argentina

Tags: microeconomics, inflation, exchange-rates, foreign-exchange

newbie here.

**Q1 -** What needs to be done by the Argentinian government for their currency to regain back its strength?

**Q2 -** Why has the Argentine Peso depreciated against the U.S Dollar for more than 18 years? What started the reasoning?

Many thanks to all that contribute to answering.

Kind regards

Nicholas